# Compute pairwise element of two 1D array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization, pairwise

Here is my problem :

let's say my two array are :

```
import numpy as np
first = np.array(["hello", "hello", "hellllo"])
second = np.array(["hlo", "halo", "alle"])
```

Now I want to get the matrix of distance between each element of the two arrays

so for example my distance function is :

```
def diff_len(string1, string2):
    return abs(len(string1) - len(string2))
```

So I I would like to get the matrix :

```
        hello       hello    hellllo

hlo    result1     result2   result3
halo   result4     result5   result6
alle   result7     result8   result9
```

So what I did was to compute row by row using vectorize function of Numpy :

```
vectorize_dist = np.vectorize(diff_len)

first = np.array(["hello", "hello", "hellllo"])
second = np.array(["hlo", "halo", "alle"])

vectorize_dist(first , "hlo")
vectorize_dist(first , "halo")
vectorize_dist(first , "alle")

matrix = np.array([vectorize_dist(first , "hlo"), vectorize_dist(first , "halo"), vectorize_dist(first , "alle")])
matrix

array([[2, 2, 4],
       [1, 1, 3],
       [1, 1, 3]])
```

But in order to get my matrix I need to execute a loop to compute row after row, but I would like to get the matrix at once.
Indeed my two arrays could be very large and executing a loop could take too much time.
also I have multiple distance to compute so I would have to execute the procedure multiple time which will be even more time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SciPy's [`cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) for that:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

def diff_len(string1, string2):
    return abs(len(string1) - len(string2))

first = np.array(["hello", "hello", "hellllo"])
second = np.array(["hlo", "halo", "alle"])
d = cdist(first[:, np.newaxis], second[:, np.newaxis], lambda a, b: diff_len(a[0], b[0]))
print(d.T)
# [[2. 2. 4.]
#  [1. 1. 3.]
#  [1. 1. 3.]]
```

Note that you would need to cast the output matrix type to make it integer though.

Comment: I have multiple distance matrix to compute, can I use multiprocessing to make use of all my cores to speed up full computation ?

Comment: @EnzoRamirezC. Yes, it should be possible to do that e.g. with a multiprocessing pool, although it has an overhead so whether or not you can get a significant performance gain will depend on the size of the problem. I'm also not sure if something like `cdist` use multiple cores already or not. You could also explore parallel Numba (in that case without `cdist`, just using loops), although to be effective your code would need to be natively jit-compilable.